# nicer way to merge list of dictionaries by key

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of dictionaries and a function that can extract a value from each of those dictionaries in the list. The goal is that i get a dictionary where the keys are the values that are returned by the given function when i pass it the dictionaries from the given list of dictionaries. The according values in the  returned dictionary should be the subset of  dictionaries from the original list of dictionaries for which the given function returned the according key.

I know this explanation is very confusing, so I'm showing it in an implementation:

```
keygen = lambda x: x['key']

data = [{'key': 'key1',
         'data': 'value2'},
        {'key': 'key3',
         'data': 'value2'},
        {'key': 'key2',
         'data': 'value2'},
        {'key': 'key2',
         'data': 'value2'},
        {'key': 'key1',
         'data': 'value2'}]

def merge_by_keygen(data, keygen):
    return_value = {} 
    for dataset in data:
        if keygen(dataset) not in return_value.keys():
            return_value[keygen(dataset)] = [] 
        return_value[keygen(dataset)].append(dataset)
    return return_value

merge_by_keygen(data, keygen)
```

returns:

```
{'key3': [{'data': 'value2', 'key': 'key3'}], 
 'key2': [{'data': 'value2', 'key': 'key2'}, {'data': 'value2', 'key': 'key2'}], 
 'key1': [{'data': 'value2', 'key': 'key1'}, {'data': 'value2', 'key': 'key1'}]}
```

I'm looking for a nicer and more compact implementation of the same logic, like some dictionary/list comprehensions. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an ideal problem to be handled by [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

**Implementation**

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
groups = groupby(sorted(data, key = itemgetter('key')), key = itemgetter('key'))
data_dict = {k : list(g) for k, g in groups}
```

or if you prefer one-liner

```
data_dict = {k : list(g) 
             for k, g in groupby(sorted(data, 
                                        key = itemgetter('key')), 
                                 key = itemgetter('key'))}
```

**Output**

```
{'key1': [{'data': 'value2', 'key': 'key1'},
          {'data': 'value2', 'key': 'key1'}],
 'key2': [{'data': 'value2', 'key': 'key2'},
          {'data': 'value2', 'key': 'key2'}],
 'key3': [{'data': 'value2', 'key': 'key3'}]}
```

Comment: A probably trivial consideration is that this calls `keygen` twice per dict - once to sort, once to groupby. If `keygen` is in fact just looking up an existing key that does not matter, but if it is computationally expensive you'd want to rework a little. I'll leave my answer up because `defaultdict`s are good to know about, but this is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using a third-party package, this is easily done with [toolz.groupby](http://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.groupby):

```
>>> import toolz
>>> toolz.groupby(keygen, data)
{'key1': [{'data': 'value2', 'key': 'key1'},
          {'data': 'value2', 'key': 'key1'}],
 'key2': [{'data': 'value2', 'key': 'key2'},
          {'data': 'value2', 'key': 'key2'}],
 'key3': [{'data': 'value2', 'key': 'key3'}]}
```

The same result is also obtained with `toolz.groupby('key', data)`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is amenable to a comprehension, but you can make it tidier using a `collections.defaultdict(list)` instance:

```
import collections

def merge_by_keygen(data, keygen):
    return_value = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for dataset in data:
        key = keygen(dataset)
        return_value[key].append(dataset)
    return return_value
```

That looks pretty clean to me - you could mess around with ways to move where you call the `keygen` function if you like but I think you'd probably lose clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it

```
return_value = {}
for d in data:
    return_value.setdefault(keygen(d), []).append(d)
```

You can write it in a list comprehension, but it's ugly to use the side effects of a list comprehension to affect data and then build up a list of None results and throw it away...

```
r = {}
[r.setdefault(keygen(d), []).append(d) for d in data]
```

The core of your function all mashes down into the [dictionary setdefault](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method. All three lines about calling the keygen, checking if the key is in the return dictionary, if it's not create an empty list, store the empty list in the dictionary, then get query the dictionary again to get the list ready to append to it - all done by setdefault().